# Reversing shared element transitions after orientation changes

Tags: android, animation, transition, element, shared

hi appreciate some help.

i have a shared element transition which works perfectly. i use supportFinishAfterTransition() to reverse the transition and it works flawlessly but if i change the orientation (from portrait to landscape for example), the reverse transition does not work. i assume it is because the position of the shared element has now changed because of the changed layout.

what do i need to do to ensure that the transition reverses correctly even after orientation change?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution that makes the reverse transition less awkward - but not perfect.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141116/1831116